# Cannot rename column name of dataframe made by .sum() function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, rename

I created a dataframe 'month' from dataframe 'user' using .sum() and .reset_index() function. I am only able to rename the 'index' column with 'Month' and cannot rename the '0' column with 'Count'. It does not throw me an error but simply display '0' instead of 'Count'. Can anyone help me with that please? Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
month = pd.DataFrame(user[['Logins in January', 'Logins in February', 'Logins in March', 'Logins in April', 'Logins in May', 'Logins in June', 'Logins in July', 'Logins in August', 'Logins in September', 'Logins in October', 'Logins in November', 'Logins in December']].sum().reset_index())

month = month.rename(columns={"index": "Month", "0": "Count"})

month
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `0` as number instead of string:

```
month.rename(columns={"index": "Month", 0: "Count"})
```